# How do I overload methods in scriptsharp now that AlternateSignature is gone?

Tags: script#

1. In the past, I've used AlternateSignature to overload methods, but in the current dev version (0.8) how do you overload methods?
2. Is it possible to overload constructors?
3. I'm probably missing something in the release notes or forums, so please let me know how you discovered the new way to overload methods. That way I know where to look in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just do the same thing you used to do, but w/o annotating as AlternateSignature.
   See https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/cc/tests/TestCases/Member/Overloads/Code.cs
2. See same test cases.
3. See https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/cc/History.txt for on-going list of changes. As you'll observe from here, the test cases also help illustrate various features.

Hope that helps.